# div float or display inline-block to left AND top

Tags: css, html

I have dynamic data in divs like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/rvWzr/

```
<div class="container">
<div style="width:200px;height:100px;">1</div>           
<div style="width:200px;height:300px;">2</div> 
<div style="width:200px;height:140px;">3</div> 
<div style="width:200px;height:210px;">4</div> 
<div style="width:200px;height:140px;">5</div> 
<div style="width:200px;height:120px;">6</div> 
</div>​

.container div{
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid black;
margin:0px 0px 20px 20px;
}​
```

On my screen it looks like this:
[image]

but i would like it to look something like this in order to not waste space:
[image]

How can i do that? Is there something like "float:left top;"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is unfortunately inexistent. You could rewrite your code into columns, but I fear that this is not enough robust when resizing.

### UPDATE

With Flexbox taking up steam (supported in all major browsers), there is at last an easy solution for the daring ones amongst us who do not fear leaving IE8/IE9 unsupported!

<kbd>**[Flexbox - Guide](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**</kbd>

<kbd>**[Flexbox - Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)**</kbd>

*If it's a badly needed feature and you need it now, I'd suggest you use a js-plugin that is doing this for you. I once used **[jq-masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)** and was quite happy with it.*