# Float left with display inline and height auto- rows working but columns stacking

Tags: css-float, vertical-alignment, blogger, multiple-columns, css

I have a total of 8 boxes with images inside. I have 4 boxes across (4 columns) in each row (2 rows total). They are set to float: left and display: inline. The columns and rows all align perfectly when the height is fixed.

Like so:
(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-o_rRBylW7Gk/UbOnL-IHSTI/AAAAAAAAFFw/udM5_Bhhz7k/s640/post-sized.PNG)

But when I add `height:auto`... the 2nd row stacks at the 3rd column.

Like so:
(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-J3dkWTM2OCw/UbOnQutKSBI/AAAAAAAAFF4/qTsBLn84ukE/s1600/post-auto.PNG)

The desired result is for all rows and columns to align without the images being skewed and stretched. As long as the desire result is achieved, I don't have a preference on how this is done (jQuery or otherwise).

I tired clear both, vertical align to top, the clearfix after, display table-cell instead of display inline, etc.. I tried everything I could find online.

Here is the CSS:

```
.post{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding: 10px;  
    background-color: white !important;
}

.post-body { 
    width: 100% !important;   
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.post img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height:auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

It's in the Blogger.com (blogspot) platform.

It's difficult to add the whole HTML, you would have to understand the Blogger format or at least XML codes but here are the main sections:

```
<b:section class='main' id='main' maxwidgets='3' showaddelement='yes'>
<b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'>
<b:includable id='main' var='top'>
<b:includable id='post' var='post'>  
<div class='post-body entry-content' expr:id='&quot;post-body-&quot; + data:post.id' itemprop='description articleBody'>
<data:post.body/>
<div style='clear: both;'/> 
</div>
</div>
</b:includable>
</b:includable>
</b:widget>
</<b:section>
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer in this page: [div float or display inline-block to left AND top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454802/div-float-or-display-inline-block-to-left-and-top?rq=1) might be a solution. JQ-Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have two main divs. One for the first line and one for the second and potentially more divs inside holding the images? If so try placing this:

```
 <div style="clear:both;">
 </div>
```

inbetween the end of the first line div and the start of the second line div

Comment: As for 2 separate divs for each row, no. The image you see is setup in a blog format. By default, it designed to show one post after another one (all 8 or however many post you have). I simply customized the blog posts instead of the default. As a result, the columns and rows are within the same section, like a blog. 

The HTML is too long to show you but after every section is that exact code. The blog does that by default.